# Python crashes on "import pdb"

Tags: python, debugging, exception, pdb

I am debugging a python script.  I have one section that is throwing IndexErrors, and I want to use pdb to find out why.  Here is my script:

```
try:
    # do stuff that throws an IndexError
except IndexError:
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

When I run the script, it crashes on the line `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`.  The traceback I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "myfile.py", line 113, in <module>
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 10, in <module>
import bdb
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 3, in <module>
import fnmatch
ImportError: No module named fnmatch
```

`import pdb`, `import bdb`, and `import fnamatch` all work without error in the python interpreter.  I don't even know where to start with this one.

**UPDATE** June 8 2016:
This question was recently brought to my attention again.  I'm afraid I don't remember this at all, what the resolution was, or even what I was working on.  I am not sure why I neglected to respond to the (good questions!) comments.  At this point I assume it was resolved - I have successfully used pdb in the last 4 years :D

What I can say at this point: I was most likely using Ubuntu (probably 12.04).

I likely would have been using a virtualenv.  Or at least thought I was using a virtualenv.  I would expect stack traces to reference something like `/home/foo/.virtualenvs/bar/...`, not `/usr/lib/python2.7`.

It might be a reach, but I recall pip didn't always use `--no-site-packages` by default.  Perhaps something installed on the system python conflicted with something in my virtualenv.  Absolute paths somewhere, or messing with PYTHONPATH in some way?

This starts to be a reach, but I'm having trouble imagining what scenario I got myself into.  This at least sounds plausible to me:

- I had package X installed in the system python.
- I created a virtualenv *without* --no-site-packages, thus pulling X into the virtualenv.
- I installed Y in the virtualenv, which conflicted with X.
- I was running my script in terminal A, in the virtualenv, and encountered the error.
- I opened terminal B, forgot to activate the virtualenv, and thus ended up using a different interpreter (credit to @DSM for this one).
- Without the virtualenv (and the hypothetical conflict), `import pdb` works fine.

I'm sorry this question appears to draw continued interest, and I only have hunches and guesses.  If you encounter this today, my suggestion would be to check the stack trace locations are what you expect.  If that's the case, check that any files referenced there actually exist, and appear to be intact.

Barring that, I would try a fresh virtualenv.

If you experience this problem and find a fix, please post it!  I'll be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: Places to start: (1) triple-check that you're using the same interpreter both times.  (2) `import fnmatch; print fnmatch` at the console to see where `fnmatch` should be found (`/usr/lib/python2.7/`, probably).  Manually edit `bdb.py` to add an `import sys; print sys.path`, to see where it's looking for it when it fails.  (3) Make sure you're running the script with the same permissions that your console has (okay, that's a stretch, but I remember once when someone here forgot to mention that sometimes he was running as root..) and make sure there's nothing strange with fnmatch's permissions.

Comment: do you have fnmatch in /usr/lib/python2.7/fnmatch.py, if not just copy it from source code of python.

Comment: What distro? DId you install using a package, or from source?